# sometimes both enter and exit method called when user in range

Tags: android, altbeacon

i am new to android developing. i am using Altbeacon lib to detect beacons and i have kontakt.io beacons. i am trying to create an app which is notify user when they enter in Region but when user first time enter the didEnterRegion() method perfectly but after some times didExitRegion() region called even when user in same Region.  i am facing some problem when user lost the region and come again it takes too much time to detect user again.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {
protected static final String TAG = "MonitoringActivity";
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
Region region;
String Eddystone_Namespace_ID="f7826da6bc5b71e0893e";
Button next;
Handler ha=new Handler();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    next=findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,TestingBeacon.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);


        beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(2000);
        beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(200);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.bind(this);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    region=new Region("myRangingUniqueId", Identifier.parse(Eddystone_Namespace_ID), null, null);
    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {

    }
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {




    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Log.e(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Near By To Beacon",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Log.e(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Beacon Range Lost",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {
                beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            Log.e(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);
        }
    });

    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

            for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "I see a beacon that is about "+beacon.getDistance()+" meters away.");
            }
        }
    });

}




@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}
```

i want user notify when they in region and same with  when exit in region.

Comment: someone comment on this post

Comment: is there is any body who can tell me. why this happening